# activemq webconsole failing

Tags: java, docker, activemq-classic

I am trying to upgrade my active,q from 5.11.1 to 5.15.14 and to also pack it in a docker image.
I faced some issues which I was able to solve with Jetty.
Now my app is working with the new activemq but for some reason I am use the web console.
I able to view it but once I try to login to see the queues I get and exception both on my browser and it the docker container:

```
 WARN | /admin/
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: [18], column: [0]) null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:162)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)[jetty-all-9.4.35.v20201120-uber.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
```

I read some comments here about using java 8 but I am using java 8 so I gues it is not the case.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
# Copy the whole directory of activemq into the image
COPY apache-activemq-5.15.14 /opt/apache-activemq-5.15.14
# Set the working directory to the bin folder 
WORKDIR /opt/apache-activemq-5.15.14/bin
# Start up the activemq server
ENTRYPOINT ["./activemq","console"]
```

Of course I am exposing the 8161 port since I am able to view the console , I just get an exception once I login.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After investigating I decided to go to a lower version of 5.15.9.
In this version all works as expected.